# Wrong intent in Alexa Skill Request when using the simulator

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I set up my intents using this intent schema:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "StartIntend"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.YesIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.NoIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

My sample utterances look like this (it's german):

```
StartIntend Hallo
StartIntend Moin
StartIntend Guten Tag
```

Why does the Amazon Developer Console generate the following request, when I use the utterance "Yes" or "Ja"?

```
{
  "session": {
    "sessionId": "SessionId...",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill...."
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.ask.account...."
    },
    "new": true
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "EdwRequestId...",
    "locale": "de-DE",
    "timestamp": "2017-02-17T21:07:59Z",
    "intent": {
      "name": "StartIntend",
      "slots": {}
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Whatever I enter, it always is using the intend `StartIntend`.

Why is that? What have I forgotten / what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked about it with the Amazon Support. After some experiments it turned out, you have to write "ja" in lowercase. It seems to be a bug in the simulator itself.

Answer (score 0):

The schema and utterance look correct.
I tried duplicating what you are seeing by performing the following steps:

1. Copied them as-is into a new skill on my account
2. Selected the North America region on the Configuration page.
3. Set the lambda to point to an existing lambda that I have. For testing purposes, I just need a valid ARN. I'm going to ignore the response anyways.
4. Then entered "Yes" into the service simulator

It indeed sent the Lambda the AMAZON.YesIntent.
So I conclude that there's nothing with the data you posted.

I tried entering Ja which resulted in the StartIntend, but I guess I would expect that since Ja is not "Yes" in North America.

Have you set the region to Europe, and entered a Lambda for the Europe region?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time trying to reproduce my issue. My region of my endpoint is set to Europe. Althogh it should not matter, my endpoint could be also hosted in NA, so I guess Amazon uses it only for connectivity purposes. The simulators service request is also having intend set to the wrong intend, although I put "yes" into the simulator.

Comment: Let me add, that I review the request directly in the left request window of the simulator, I don't debug my service to see the actual request. But it should be 1:1 the same, right?

Comment: Yes, I would expect them to be the same.

Comment: Just to let you know, I found the solution for this problem: The Simulator seems to have a small bug: You had to type "ja" in lowercase.

Comment: Ha! Ok, then. Glad you got it worked out, and thanks for sharing the answer.

Answer (score -1):

When creating the skill in the Alexa Skills Kit, you need to choose the correct language i.e. German, see screenshot below.

Everything else seems to be correct.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. My language is set to German. Did you try to reproduce it?